# asp.net button click even can not work

Tags: asp.net

button click event can not work in asp.net c# page. asp.net Validation use in this form.

```
 <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup1">
                <div style="border-top: 1px #CCCCCC dotted; text-align: right; padding: 5px 5px 0px 0px; color: #ff5400;">
                    Fields marked * are mandatory</div>
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="mo" />
                <div alin="centre">
                    <div class="form-field1 pB10 pT20 " style="width: 40%;">
                        <label>
                            <span style="text-align: left;">Select</span>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlUserType1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Deal" Selected="True">&nbsp;&nbsp;Dealers</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Dist">&nbsp;&nbsp;Distributors</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Supp">&nbsp;&nbsp;Suppliers</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field1 pB10 pT20" style="float: left; width: 40%;">
                        <label>
                            <span style="text-align: left;">Select Country </span>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlSelectCountry1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="in" Selected="True">&nbsp;&nbsp;INDIA</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="ov">&nbsp;&nbsp;OVERSEAS</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field1 pT10" style="margin-left: -20px; padding-bottom: 10px; clear: both;">
                    <label>
                        <span>Title*</span>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelect1" runat="server" CssClass="form-bg1" Style="width: 170px;">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="SELECT">SELECT</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Mr.</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Mrs.</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Ms.</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Dr.</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" InitialValue="SELECT" ValidationGroup="mo" ControlToValidate="ddlSelect1" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ErrorMessage="Please enter Title">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field1" style="margin-left: -20px; padding-bottom: 10px; clear: both;">
                    <label>
                        <span>First Name*</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName1" CssClass="form-bg1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" ValidationGroup="mo" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName1" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ErrorMessage="Please enter First Name">*
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="mo" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid First Name" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName1" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field1" style="margin-left: -20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label>
                        <span>Last Name*</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName1" CssClass="form-bg1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastName1" ValidationGroup="mo" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ErrorMessage="Please enter Last Name">*
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid Last Name" ValidationGroup="mo" ControlToValidate="txtLastName1" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field1" style="margin-left: -20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label>
                        <span>Company Name*</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany1" CssClass="form-bg1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator16" runat="server" ValidationGroup="mo" ControlToValidate="txtCompany1" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ErrorMessage="Please enter Company Name">* </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field1" style="margin-left: -20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label>
                        <span>Current Business*</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrentBusiness1" CssClass="form-bg1" Columns="40" Rows="4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator17" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCurrentBusiness1" ValidationGroup="mo" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ErrorMessage="Please enter Current Business">*
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field1" style="margin-left: -20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label>
                        <span>Email Address*</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail1" CssClass="form-bg1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator18" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail1" ValidationGroup="mo" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ErrorMessage="Please enter Email Address">*
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" Style="width: 10px;" ValidationGroup="mo" ErrorMessage="Please enter Valid Email" ControlToValidate="txtEmail1" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field1" style="margin-left: -20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <label>
                        <span>Phone*</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone1" CssClass="form-bg1" runat="server" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator19" runat="server" ValidationGroup="mo" ControlToValidate="txtPhone1" Display="Dynamic" Style="width: 10px;" ErrorMessage="Please enter Phone">*
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>

                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>
                <div style="border-top: 1px #CCCCCC dotted; text-align: right; padding: 5px 5px 0px 0px; color: #999999; margin-top: 10px;">
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div style="margin-left: 15%;">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit11" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="submit-bt2" ValidationGroup="mo" OnClick="btnSubmit11_Click"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReset1" runat="server" Text="Reset" CssClass="submit-bt" OnClick="btnReset1_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                </div>
            </div>

protected void btnSubmit11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  //code

}
protected void btnReset1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: Is there any validation fire or some error ?

Comment: no error get only click no response

Comment: only validation on submit button, but reset button also cannot work my page. in my page two submit one off working but second button cannot work

Comment: Its working I have Checked. On Reset what you are doing ?...

Answer (score 0):

1)  Try changing your onclick method from: OnClick="btnSubmit11_Click" to OnClick="btnSubmit_Click". Just remove the number 11. Do the same for your code-behind method as well.

2)   Rebuild your project.

3)  If that doesn't work, drag a new button in your page via Visual Studio design view and double click on the Button to generate the event handler. Then add your code existing code from your old button event (btnSubmit11_Click) to the new one.

Comment: i have try new button add but that not work <asp:Button ID="btnresetmo" runat="server" Text="Reset New" CssClass="submit-bt" onclick="btnresetmo_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>

Comment: chek this url http://clients.alfadesign.co.in/symphony/products/become-an-associate.aspx show in mobile screen in browser

Comment: this problem can not solved. this error found in cs page "The name 'control name' does not exist in the current context" control already exist in .aspx page

Comment: ok then just try this ..delete the designer.cs file of that page and than right click on the page and select convert to web application than select "yes" in prompt .

Comment: than go for the new button and on click event for that button.